# How to Get and Set Formulas as a text string with GetFormulas and SetFormulas?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I need a bit of help figuring out how to get and set formulas in App Script while converting them to text strings in-between. For example:

I have 3 sheets, Sheet 1 contains source formulas, Sheet 2 that is supposed to store the source formulas as strings (acting as a database), Sheet 3 where I'm supposed to set formulas that I get from Sheet 2 .

Sheet1!A1 contains formula "=B1*C1"

Sheet1!A2 contains formula "=B2*C2"

etc.

Sheet2!A1:A is blank.

Sheet3!A1:A is blank.

What I need to achieve:

Task A. I would like to get all formulas from Sheet1!A1:A with the getFormulas() method and then store them as a text string in Sheet2!A1:A with setValues() method but I have no idea how to convert the array generated by getFormulas() into strings that I can then store with setValues(). Something like this:

```
var formulas = s.getRange('Sheet1!A1:A').getFormulas();
s.getRange('Sheet2!A1:A').setValues(formulas.toString());
```

Problem is of course that I get a method signature mismatch if I try to use toString().

Task B. After storing the formula strings in Sheet2!A1:A, I would like to get them with getValues() then set them as formulas in Sheet3!A1:A with setFormulas().

```
var text_formulas = s.getRange('Sheet2!A1:A').getValues();
s.getRange('Sheet3!A1:A').setFormulas(text_formulas);
```

Any idea how I could go about achieving this in an efficient manner? Thank you in advance for helping out a novice!

Comment: Hints: Formulas are strings. When set using `setValues` or `setFormulas`, they get evaluated. You can prepend a single quote `'` before each of the formula(using  ``array.map``) to prevent formula string from evaluating.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @TheMaster! I'm trying to use map to prepend a quote but I cant seem to figure out how to add it to all elements, not just the rows. var formulatext = sourceFormulas.getFormulas().map((r) => ["\'" + r]);

Comment: Assuming it's just 1 column, try ```const prependedFormulas= sourceFormulas.getFormulas().map((r) => [`'` + r[0]]);```